# Axis label not in desired place

Tags: pgfplots

I want to ask how to put the y label above the vertical line on the left instead of on top of 0. And also explain to me the meaning of the code in your answer.

Picture:

[image: Yeah]

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=-4:4, samples=100,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=10cm,
  xtick={0}, ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major]
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};
\draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2,0) -- node [fill=white] {\small $z=2$} (axis cs:0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Change the `every axis y label` style to

```
every axis y label/.style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},anchor=south},
```

The `rel axis cs` coordinate system has (0,0) in the lower left corner, and (1,1) in the top right, so (0,1) is the top right corner.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=-4:4, samples=100,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
  every axis y label/.style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=10cm,
  xtick={0}, ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major]
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};
  \draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2,0) -- node [fill=white] {\small $z=2$} (axis cs:0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

or simple `every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=-4:4, samples=100,
%
  axis lines=left, 
  xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
  every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=10cm,
  xtick={0}, ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major]
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};
\draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2,0) -- node [fill=white] {\small $z=2$} (axis cs:0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How does this work? Is an appropriate coordinate system automatically chosen for `every axis label`?

Comment: @pschulz, it seem so :-). Actually,  coordinate `(0,1) means, that it is on the top of the left side of the graph, where is placed y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different coordinate systems for this, possible is for example the `rel axis cs` or the `axis description cs`. But in my opinion, the best is to use the right coordinate system for the respective axis: `xticklabel* cs` and `yticklabel* cs` (if you don't use the stars, the tick labels are also considered, which can be handy. This is not needed here)

Here is your code with the modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat = 1.14 % n=most recent feature set, not necessarily needed
}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            no markers, 
            domain=-4:4, 
            samples=100,
            axis x line=bottom, % place axis explicitly
            axis y line=left, 
            xlabel=$x$, 
            ylabel=$y$,
            every axis y label/.style={at={(yticklabel* cs: 1)}, anchor = south}, % change here
            every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel* cs: 1)}, anchor = west}, % change here
            height=5cm, width=10cm,
            xtick={0}, ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
            grid = major
        ]
        \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-4:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
        \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};
        \draw [yshift=-0.6cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2,0) -- node [fill=white] {\small $z=2$} (axis cs:0,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```